# Hosting a ruby site on localhost?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gulp, localhost

How to locally host this website package i got, I am PHP developer, and this package my client gave me contains of ruby gem files. Can anyone let me know step by step process for mac?

[this is how the package looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gotfp.png)

I tried installing gem bundle and packages, but not able to host it locally.

Comment: That is not a rails app. Honestly I am not sure what that is because it does not resemble any ruby web application I have ever seen. No rackup file, no rb files that I can see at all

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step by step tutorial to launch you first ruby on rails server.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-installation.htm

When everything is set you launch your server with this command : `rails server`

Your server is now accessible here : `http://localhost:3000`

Answer (score 0):

Step 2 from the below tutorial will get your site up and running on localhost.

https://www.theodinproject.com/courses/web-development-101/lessons/your-first-rails-application

First, you need to install Rails

```
gem install rails
```

Then navigate to your project folder and start your local server with

```
rails server
```

Comment: That directory structure is definitely not a rails application